# Average all other columns based on one column in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate, average, mean

I need to average a large number of columns based on the name in another column. My matrix looks like this (with separate unique row names):

```
Names       X1  Y1  Z1  X2  Y2  Z2
P.maccus    4   2   2   6   5   3
P.maccus    6   5   3   7   6   5
P.maccus    8   3   2   8   7   3
A.ammophius 3   6   2   7   5   5
P.sabaji    2   5   3   8   4   5
P.sabaji    4   6   3   9   6   5
P.sabaji    5   7   2   8   7   3
P.sabaji    3   5   3   9   5   4
```

I need to average each row to look like this:

```
Names       X1  Y1      Z1      X2  Y2  Z2
P.maccus    6   3.33    2.33    7   6   3.66
A.ammophius 3   6       2       7   5   5
P.sabaji    3.5 5.75    2.75    8.5 5.5 4.25
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is a simpler form of that. You want to use `groupby` and `summarize` from the `dplyr` package

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy with `dplyr`. you can do

```
dd %>% group_by(Names) %>% summarize_all(mean)
```

tested with the following data

```
dd<-read.table(text="Names       X1  Y1  Z1  X2  Y2  Z2
P.maccus    4   2   2   6   5   3
P.maccus    6   5   3   7   6   5
P.maccus    8   3   2   8   7   3
A.ammophius 3   6   2   7   5   5
P.sabaji    2   5   3   8   4   5
P.sabaji    4   6   3   9   6   5
P.sabaji    5   7   2   8   7   3
P.sabaji    3   5   3   9   5   4", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate()` for that.

Assuming your data matrix is in variable named `df`:

```
aggregate(. ~ Names, data=df, FUN=mean)

        Names  X1       Y1       Z1  X2  Y2       Z2
1 A.ammophius 3.0 6.000000 2.000000 7.0 5.0 5.000000
2    P.maccus 6.0 3.333333 2.333333 7.0 6.0 3.666667
3    P.sabaji 3.5 5.750000 2.750000 8.5 5.5 4.250000
```